# who to set JAXWS 2.2 client timeout

Tags: java, timeout, client, jax-ws

i have simple JAXWS client with dynamic url.
i want to add timeout . but all the eamples i found here , dosn't look like my client.
here is my code :

```
QName qname = new QName(responseUrl,"sendMessage"); 
        MyApiService myApiService = new myApiService(newEndpoint,qname);         
        myApi port = myApiService.getmyApiPort();



        NPACK nPACK = port.sendMessage(nPMESSAGE);
```

how do i implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148915/how-do-i-set-the-timeout-for-a-jax-ws-webservice-client) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130913/setting-jax-ws-client-timeout) in my client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext()...
```