# Set Java Endpoint timeout duration

Tags: java, web-services, timeout, jax-ws

I am implementing a simple Java web service using JAX-WS exposing my service using @WebService and @WebMethod

To publish the service I am using a simple Endpoint.publish() implementation

```
Endpoint.publish( "http://urlToService" , new WebServiceImp() );
```

all of which is working correctly.

I am now in a situation where I need to set the timeout duration of a users connection.
From my searching I have found many instances of people implementing this on client side applications on their requests, I also found way of changing config files for application servers like Tomcat. But not a way to set values for the endpoint

So my question is, 
a) How can I set the default timeout for communicating with the endpoint
b) How can I see the current timeout value for endpoint communication.

Many Thanks

Comment: This question may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130913/setting-jax-ws-client-timeout

Comment: Yeah this is a page i found before but from what I understand the above few implementations use the Service class ( something I'm not use ) I believe this is used when a client is connecting to an existing web service (unless I am mistaken). The other suggestion on this post which seemed possible is the setting of the JRE props 
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout
sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout 
props but I cannot see the client package so not sure a) how to implement such a think b) if it would have an effect due to lack of packages?
Thanks for your responce